# Overwriting data when calling the flow terminal operator

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Good afternoon, I have a rather serious problem when using the flow terminal operator. I have an application that takes data from the network and sorts it based on whether it is in the cache or not. In order to update the list immediately when the data in the database has changed, I use flow.

CacheDataSource:

```kotlin
//CacheDataSource
override suspend fun getData(): Flow<List<FilmCache>> {
            return filmFavoritesDao.getFavoritesFilmsList()
        }
//FilmFavoriteDAO
@Dao
interface FilmFavoritesDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM favorites_films_list ORDER BY id DESC")
    fun getFavoritesFilmsList(): Flow<List<FilmCache>>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertFavoritesFilm(film: FilmCache)
}
```

In the integrator, I get data from the network, and if successful, I will transform the list into the form I need.

```kotlin
//NetworkResult
sealed class NetworkResult<T>( val data: T,  val errorType: ErrorType) {
    class Success<T>(data: T) : NetworkResult<T>(data, ErrorType.UNIT)
    class Error<T>(errorMessage: ErrorType) : NetworkResult<T>(Unit as T, errorMessage) {
        class NotFound<T>() : NetworkResult<T>(errorType = ErrorType.UNIT, data = Unit as T)
    }
    class Loading<T> : NetworkResult<T>(Unit as T, ErrorType.UNIT)
}
```

In the integrator, I get data from the network, and if successful, I will transform the list into the form I need.

```kotlin
//Interactor
override suspend fun testFetchSearchFilms(keywords: String) = flow {
            scope.launch {
                topFilms.emit(listOf(FilmUi.Progress))
                when (val data = filmRepository.fetchSearchMovie(keywords)) {
                    is NetworkResult.Success -> {
                        cacheDataSource.getData().collectLatest { 
                            //when flow collect networkList data in changed, but it shouldn't 
                            val cachedList = it 
                            val networkList = data.data
                            val compareList =
                                favoriteFilmsComparisonMapper.compare(networkList, cachedList)
                            emit(compareList)
                        }
                    }
                    is NetworkResult.Error -> emit(listOf(FilmUi.Failed(errorToUi.map(data.errorType))))
                    is NetworkResult.Error.NotFound -> emit(listOf(FilmUi.Failed.FilmNotFound()))
                    is NetworkResult.Loading -> emit(listOf(FilmUi.Progress))
                }
            }
        }
```

This code really works well, but when the terminal operator is called, it doesn't matter which collect, onEach, flatMerge or any other, there is another list in the NetworkList variable, i.e. the one that the user received before.
Just in case, here's an example ViewModel:

```
class SearchFilmsViewModel(
    private val filmsInteractor: FilmInteract,
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _searchText: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

    private val _searchFilms: MutableLiveData<List<FilmUi>> = MutableLiveData()
    val searchFilms: LiveData<List<FilmUi>> = _searchFilms

    fun load(keywords: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            filmsInteractor.testFetchSearchFilms(keywords)
                .collectLatest {
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        _searchFilms.value = it
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    fun itemToCache(item: FilmUi) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            filmsInteractor.addOrRemoveFilm(item)
        }
    }
}
```

I will be very grateful for any ideas on this issue.

I tried to replace flow with live Data, but I got a similar result, I also tried different versions of flow, both hot and cold

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue lies in the usage of the `collectLatest` operator. This operator gathers all the flow's emitted values and sends them as a single batch. As a result, the `compareList` function will receive the same list of values, regardless of any updates in the database.

To fix this issue, you can use the `collect` operator instead of `collectLatest`, modify your code as follows:

```kotlin
override suspend fun testFetchSearchFilms(keywords: String) = flow {
    topFilms.emit(listOf(FilmUi.Progress))
    val networkData = filmRepository.fetchSearchMovie(keywords)
    if (networkData is NetworkResult.Success) {
        cacheDataSource.getData().collect { cachedList ->
            val networkList = networkData.data
            val compareList = favoriteFilmsComparisonMapper.compare(networkList, cachedList)
            emit(compareList)
        }
    } else {
        when (networkData) {
            is NetworkResult.Error -> emit(listOf(FilmUi.Failed(errorToUi.map(networkData.errorType))))
            is NetworkResult.Error.NotFound -> emit(listOf(FilmUi.Failed.FilmNotFound()))
            is NetworkResult.Loading -> emit(listOf(FilmUi.Progress))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I said, this problem does not depend on the terminal operator, whether it is collect, collect Latest, onEach or any other. When I use debag, it can be seen that the value in the list from the network is changing, although this cannot be, new data from the network is not being requested at this moment